# Insert data mysqli and php in form 1 and return to new form 2

Tags: php, forms, mysqli

Hi all I am new to mysqli and php (currently studying and trying to work on a test database- I have not used security measures at this wont be available public) and trying to get the information I have just submitted in the form to display in a new form which will then receive further user input then submitted to database.  Here is an example of what I have done so far:

Form 1 (customer table - cust id =primary key)
Customer Details ie name address telephone etc
dynamic drop down box - consists of 4 options.( would like whatever option is selected here to return a particular form)

The form is currently submitting correctly in the database, but I would like once it has submitted to the database to return the customer info (including the customer id as that is the relationship in the new table) and on the  **form2**(service table - service id is primary key) so the user can input further data to the form and submit.

Hope this makes sense, any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Response 1
Thank you for my response I probably havent made myself very clear.

Form 1 where dynamic dropdown list is - when user submits forms I would like it to return form 2 with the customer info we inserted in form 1

**Form 1**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="newbookingcode.php" method="post">
<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname"/>
    Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname"/></p>
    <p>Business Name: <input type="text" name="businessname"/></p>
<p>Contact Number: <input type="text" name="number"/>
 Alt Number: <input type="text" name="altno"></p>
<p>Email Address:<input type="text" name="email"></p>
  <p>Street No:<input tyep="text" name="streetno">
   Street Name:<input type="text" name="street"></p>
    <p>Suburb:<input type="text" name="suburb">
  Postal Code:<input type="text" name="postalcode">
    State: <input type="text" name="state"></p>

     **<p>Type of Service Required: <select id="category" name="category" > 
<option value="nill">---Select Service---</option**

<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM serviceType";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<option value= "'.$row['jobType'].'" >' . $row['jobType'] . '</option>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
</p>
 </select>
 <p>
    <input type="submit"/>
</p>
       </form>   

</body>
</html>
```

**Query in separate file**

> ```
> $fname=$_POST['firstname'];
> $lname=$_POST['lastname'];
> $bname=$_POST['businessname'];
> $phone=$_POST['number'];
> $altphone=$_POST['altno'];
> $email=$_POST['email'];
> $streetno=$_POST['streetno'];
> $street=$_POST['street'];
> $suburb=$_POST['suburb'];
> $postcode=$_POST['postalcode'];
> $state=$_POST['state'];
> $service=$_POST['category'];
>
>
>
>
> // Create connection
> $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
> // Check connection
> if ($conn->connect_error) {
>     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
> } 
>
> $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (contactFirstName,contactLastName,businessName,contactNumber,altNumber,email,streetNo,streetName,suburb,postalCode,state,serviceType)
> VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$bname','$phone','$altphone','$email','$streetno','$street','$suburb','$postcode','$state','$service')";
>
>
>
> if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
>     echo "New record created successfully";
> } else {
>     echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
> }
> $conn->close();
> ?>
> ```

Comment: Ok, so what you need help with?

Comment: I think you want this: After inserting the record: $database->insert_id. This will give you the id of the created record.

Comment: Thank you for my response I probably havent made myself very clear, i would like to know what syntax to use when I submit form 1.  Here is a copy of what I have done so far, I am sure it is incorrect way of writing code but it working to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a database object like `mysqli` to do DB interactions.
 Say `form1` generate insert query `$insertQyery`.
And you are executing this query (insert statement) like

```
$mysqli->query($insertQyery);
```

After the execution of this insert statement you can use

```
$customerId = $mysqli->insert_id
```

Now using this `$customerId` you can show records details on `form2` or use this `$customerId` as reference on `form2`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this code and let me know if you have any questions:

```
<?php
$servername = "";
$username = "";
$password = "";
$dbname = "";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM serviceType";
$result = $conn->query($sql);



/************** IMPORTANT *************/
$whichForm = 1;//to know which form to show
$last_customer_id = 0;//to store last customer id
//to store your customer information
$fname=$lname=$bname=$phone=$altphone=$email=$streetno=$street=$suburb=$postcode=$state=$service='';


//To handle post operations after clicking on post.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
 $whichForm = 2; // to show second form

 //if it is first form
 if($_POST['action'] == 'firstForm')
 {
      $fname=$_POST['firstname'];
      $lname=$_POST['lastname'];
      $bname=$_POST['businessname'];
      $phone=$_POST['number'];
      $altphone=$_POST['altno'];
      $email=$_POST['email'];
      $streetno=$_POST['streetno'];
      $street=$_POST['street'];
      $suburb=$_POST['suburb'];
      $postcode=$_POST['postalcode'];
      $state=$_POST['state'];
      $service=$_POST['category'];
      //Preparing your insert query
      $sql = "INSERT INTO customer (contactFirstName,contactLastName,businessName,contactNumber,altNumber,email,streetNo,streetName,suburb,postalCode,state,serviceType) VALUES ('$fname','$lname','$bname','$phone','$altphone','$email','$streetno','$street','$suburb','$postcode','$state','$service')";
      $conn->query($sql); //insert into db
      //get last insert customer id and you already have your customer information
      //in the variables above $fname, $lname.....etc
      $last_customer_id = $conn->insert_id;
 }
 else{//do something with your second form

      //get last customer info
      $sql = "SELECT * FROM serviceType where id = ".$POST_['last_customer_id']."";
      $result = $conn->query($sql);
      $res = $result->fetch_assoc();
      //you can access customer information like res['contactFirstName']

     }
}

$conn->close(); //close your connection

?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if($whichForm == 1){ //if it is first form
?>

<form id="1" action="test2.php" method="post">
     <!-- This input is needed to identify which form -->
     <input type="hidden" name="action" value="firstForm" />
     <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $fname; ?>"/>
     Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lname; ?>" /></p>
     <p>Business Name: <input type="text" name="businessname" value="<?php echo $bname; ?>"/></p>
     <p>Contact Number: <input type="text" name="number" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/>
     Alt Number: <input type="text" name="altno" value="<?php echo $altphone; ?>"></p>
     <p>Email Address:<input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"></p>
     <p>Street No:<input tyep="text" name="streetno" value="<?php echo $streetno; ?>">
     Street Name:<input type="text" name="street" value="<?php echo $street; ?>"></p>
     <p>Suburb:<input type="text" name="suburb" value="<?php echo $suburb; ?>">
     Postal Code:<input type="text" name="postalcode" value="<?php echo $postcode; ?>">
     State: <input type="text" name="state" value="<?php echo $state; ?>"></p>
 **<p>Type of Service Required: <select id="category" name="category" > 
 <option value="nill">---Select Service---</option>
 <?php
      if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
          // output data of each row
          while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                //this if to save the value of the selected category
                if($row['jobType'] == $service)
                {
                     echo '<option value= "'.$row['jobType'].'" SELECTED>' . $row['jobType'] . '</option>';
                }
                else
                {
                     echo '<option value= "'.$row['jobType'].'">' . $row['jobType'] . '</option>';
                }

          }
      }
 ?>
    </select></p>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
}//ending bracket for if($whichForm == 1)
else if($whichForm == 2){ // or just else will do fine 
?>

<form id="2" action="test2.php" method="post">
<!-- This input is needed to identify which form -->
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="secondForm" />
<!-- This input is needed to store the last customer id -->
<input type="hidden" name="last_customer_id" value="<?php echo $last_customer_id; ?>" />

<!-- here you put your second form -->

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<?php 
}//ending bracket for else if($whichForm == 2)
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to produce this information, I will implement it and let you know how I go.

Answer (score -1):

After customer submit FORM #1

on the next page

let's get the last customer details :-

```
<?php

//after mysqli connection

$contactFirstName = '';
$contactLastName = '';
$businessName = '';

$sql_get_data = "SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY customerID DESC limit 1 ";
$query_get_data = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_get_data);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query_get_data, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    //specify which data you want to get from "customer" table 
    $contactFirstName = $row['contactFirstName'];
    $contactLastName = $row['contactLastName'];
    $businessName = $row['businessName'];
}
?>
```

HTML Form#2 :-

```
<form id="form2" method="post">
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo 'contactFirstName'; ?>"
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo 'contactLastName'; ?>"
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo 'businessName'; ?>"
</form>
```

Hope this answer will help you.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the sql query and that produced the results I am after but I am confused and how to create the necessary files.  Is the syntax you gave me two seperate files? or can they be put in one .php file?  I am not sure what I am supposed to enter in these fields? $contactFirstName = '';
$contactLastName = '';
$businessName = '';